# can't understand the test(event.button) method

Tags: javascript, regex

1.I can't understand the conditions in the if(), so what does event.button mean?2. what does the number 2|6|4|7 mean in the regex? is the number have some special connection with the even.button? anyone helps me please? thanks!

```
  eleLink[index].onmouseup = function(event) {
            event = event || window.event;
            var target = this;
            if (/^2|6|4|7$/.test(event.button)) {
                target.style.visibility = "hidden";
                setTimeout(function() { target.style.visibility = "visible";}, 16);            
            }        
        };
```

Comment: @hallucinations: That MDN page is mistaken, -1 is not a valid value, since `button` only relates to events where a button changed state. MDN isn't the documentation for events, it's a meta site (a good one, usually); [the spec for `button` is here](https://www.w3.org/TR/uievents/#widl-MouseEvent-button). Also, FWIW, that regex doesn't do what you described (and the author intended), the alternations don't apply the way the author seems to have assumed (see my answer for details).

Answer (score 1):

On a mouse event, `button` is the button that was related to the event. `/^2|6|4|7$/.test(event.button)` will coerce `event.button` to a string and then test that string against that regular expression. The expression is *probably* meant to test that the button is 2, 6, 4, or 7. It doesn't do that, because the alternations don't apply the way the author thought they did; instead, it tests whether the button number, converted to a string, *starts with* 2, contains 6 or 4, or *ends with* 7. To get the alternation the author probably meant, they'd need `/^(?:2|6|4|7)$/`.

The code doesn't make a lot of sense, though. [`MouseEvent#button`](https://www.w3.org/TR/uievents/#widl-MouseEvent-button) is defined to have the values 0, 1, or 2, to indicate which button changed state: 0 for the primary (usually left) button, 1 for the auxilliary (middle or similar) button, and 2 for the secondary (usually right) button. The author may have been dealing with a browser that did non-standard things, or may have confused `button` with [`MouseEvent#buttons`](https://www.w3.org/TR/uievents/#widl-MouseEvent-buttons) (plural), which is a bitmask of the buttons that are currently down: 0 = None, 1 = primary, 2 = secondary, 4 = auxilliary, and then further bitflag values for custom buttons.